# Escaping equal sign in Apache Mod_Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

How would you rewrite a url that contain special characters (e.g. equal sign). Escaping the character does not seem to work for me. (Though it [should](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^?cat\=4$ http://www.example.com/research [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The equal sign is not special in a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to escape is not the equal sign, it is the question sign

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\?cat=4$ http://www.example.com/research [R=301,NC,L]
```

As Ignacio already pointed in his comment, the equal sign is not a special char in a regular expression